# How to get values from message bundle?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, resourcebundle

In my application configuration class, I have the following entry:

```
    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt_BR"));
        return resolver;
    }
```

The `message_pt_BR.properties` is located according to the attached image.

[image]

I'm trying to access an entry on this with a `<span th:text="#{app.name}"></span>` file and all I get is:

```
??app.name_pt_br??
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message bundle name should be

```
messages_pt_BR.properties
```

It's case sensitive.

It's OK without default message bundle(messages.properties). Mine works fine with only _en and _zh_TW.

And it should be ok that you put your resource bundle everywhere if you give the correct path to set basename.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Blithe! So, for the scenario on the image I posted, `messageSource.setBasename("/i18n/messages");` should be OK, right?

Comment: If it's still not working, maybe you should try <spring:message code="keyInPropertyFile"></spring:message> first to narrow down the problem cause. Remember to add taglib.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. Thanks, though! I'll try the tag lib approach, for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your `messages` bundle to `/resources` folder.
Also you need to add `messages.properties` bundle, it's required.

Comment: Yes, try to add it to `/i18n/messages.properties`.

Comment: Even though specifying like this, the application does not "sees" the file and the displayed result is the same

Comment: aha, I see you added it to `/webapp` package, try to replace it to `/resources` folder.

Comment: the correct basename should be, then, `/resources/messages.properties`?

Comment: No, `basename` must be the same as now. Just replace `messages*` files to `/resources/i18n/` folder. I tried it on my project - it works.

Comment: No luck, buddy! For the moment this is a minor problem. I'm working on some lists now.